# Insert data to MySql with loop instead of one by one

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

My Html code is below:

```
<form name="creditAssessPage2" id="basicform" method="post" action="post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="finanIns1" id="finanIns1" value=""></td>

        <td id="balance"><input type="number" name="balance1" id="balance1" value="" min="0"></td>
        <td id="MonthyComm"><input type="number" name="monthlyComm1" id="monthlyComm1" value="" min="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="finanIns2" id="finanIns2" value=""></td>

        <td id="balance"><input type="number" name="balance2" id="balance2" value="" min="0"></td>
        <td id="MonthyComm"><input type="number" name="monthlyComm2" id="monthlyComm2" value="" min="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="finanIns3" id="finanIns3" value=""></td>

        <td id="balance"><input type="number" name="balance3" id="balance3" value="" min="0"></td>
        <td id="MonthyComm"><input type="number" name="monthlyComm3" id="monthlyComm3" value="" min="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

</form>
```

My post.php code is below:

```
    require_once 'db/dbfunction.php';
    require_once 'db/dbCreditAssessment.php';

    session_start();
    $con = open_connection();
$finanIns1 = $_POST['finanIns1'];
$balance1 = $_POST['balance1'];
$monthlyComm1 = $_POST['monthlyComm1'];

$finanIns2 = $_POST['finanIns2'];
$balance2 = $_POST['balance2'];
$monthlyComm2 = $_POST['monthlyComm2'];

$finanIns3 = $_POST['finanIns3'];
$balance3 = $_POST['balance3'];
$monthlyComm3 = $_POST['monthlyComm3'];

addemployementdetails($con,$finanIns1,$balance1,$monthlyComm1);
addemployementdetails($con,$finanIns2,$balance2,$monthlyComm2);
addemployementdetails($con,$finanIns3,$balance3,$monthlyComm3);

close_connection($con);
```

my dbCreditAssessment.php code is below:

```
function addemployementdetails($con,$finanIns1,$balance1,$monthlyComm1){

    $query = "insert into employementdetails(finance,balance,monthlycomm) 
            values('$finanIns1','$balance1','$monthlyComm1')";            
                 //echo "{$sqlString}";



                 $insertResult = mysqli_query($con, $query);


                 if($insertResult){
                     echo " Applicant Detail Added !<br />";
                     echo "<a href='index.php'>Back to Home</a>";
                 }
                 else {
                     echo " Error !";
                     echo "{$query}";
                     //header('Location: post.php');
                 }                                  
}
```

this function will repeat 3 times. 
Actually, there are a lot more of the same fields to key in. e.g. finanIns1, finanIns2, finanIns3, finanIns4, finanIns5, ect.

Is there any way to use a loop to replace this way of inserting data?
Also, if the fields are empty, the data will not be inserted to Mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, count the finanIns occurrence in the $_POST array. Then use 'for' function to loop it.

```
$count = count(preg_grep("/^finanIns[\d]*/", array_keys($_POST)));

for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++){ 
    $finanIns = $_POST['finanIns'.$i];
    $balance = $_POST['balance'.$i];
    $monthlyComm = $_POST['monthlyComm'.$i];

    addemployementdetails($con,$finanIns,$balance,$monthlyComm);
}
```

Remember to sanitize those inputs using mysqli_real_escape_string and trim. Change your code to this:

```
$count = count(preg_grep("/^finanIns[\d]*/", array_keys($_POST)));

for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++){ 
    $finanIns = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['finanIns'.$i]));
    $balance = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['balance'.$i]));
    $monthlyComm = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['monthlyComm'.$i]));

    addemployementdetails($con,$finanIns,$balance,$monthlyComm);
}
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

this might help.

```
for($i = 1 ; $i < 4 ; $i++){ 
  $finanIns = $_POST['finanIns'.$i];
  $balance = $_POST['balance3'.$i];
  $monthlyComm = $_POST['monthlyComm3'.$i];
  if($finanIns != "" && $balance != "" && $monthlyComm != ""){
    addemployementdetails($con,$finanIns,$balance,$monthlyComm);
  }
}
```

another code snippet

IF number of inputs are user desired.then you need to add a hidden input that holds the number of table row that contains the finanIns,balance,monthlyComm inputs.

you can put name="finanIns[]" if you have 3 or more inputs there. if YES then just use it and access the value as $_POST['finanIns'][$i]

```
for($i = 1 ; $i < $_POST['number_of_inputs']  ; $i++){ 
  $finanIns = $_POST['finanIns'][$i];
  $balance = $_POST['balance'][$i];
  $monthlyComm = $_POST['monthlyComm'][$i];
  if($finanIns != "" && $balance != "" && $monthlyComm != ""){
    addemployementdetails($con,$finanIns,$balance,$monthlyComm);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to make changes to the HTML code? like name="finanIns[]"

Comment: you can put name="finanIns[]" if you have 3 or more inputs there. if YES then just use it and access the value as `$_POST['finanIns'][$i]`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of fields you have (1,2,3) what you can do is a for loop in php:

```
// make a loop to go according to the number of fields you have
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){ 
    // assign the fields value to the variables
    $finanIns = $_post['finanIns'.$i];
    $balance = $_post['balance'.$i];
    $monthlyComm = $_post['monthlyComm'.$i];
    //check if fields are empty, if not, insert to mysql
    if($finanIns != "" && $balance != "" && $monthlyComm != ""){
        addemployementdetails($con,$finanIns,$balance,$monthlyComm);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if it's working :)